# How would I use both absolute and relative tags to position a CSS div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to have the default vertical position for certain divs to be relative: so that they are right under the element on top. But I want to be able to define their horizontal position. for example, left: 30px but top can be variable. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You can make use of `margin-left` to offset a relative element from the left. Same with `margin-top`. But other than suggesting those two, I can't help much, as I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Could you add a bit more context and perhaps some sample code?

Comment: can you produce some code which you have tried to better understand your issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; /*to avoid overflow because of 'left:30px' given to wrapper2*/
}
.wrapper1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
.wrapper2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 30px;
}
.child1 {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}
.child2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1"></div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

For increasing the relative distance between both the `wrappers`, you can use `margin-top` or `bottom`

Hope it helps!